# Interval Notation of the Following Logarithmic Inequality

Tags: inequality, logarithms, interval-arithmetic

So after trying to solve the following inequality, log(x) + log(2-x) < 1
I couldn't end up with any answer since as I tried to solve here are my results

**First I got my reference equation** ( to be used in the number line )
log(x)+log(2-x)<1

As I tried solving it

x(2-x)<10

x(2-x)-10<0

x^2 + 2x -10 <0

**I multiply both sides by negative 1**

x^2 - 2x + 10 > 0

**But as you can see the following is not factorable.**

*I decided to try using Symbolab and Wolfram to see what was the Interval notation and it answered (0,2)*

Can someone please help enlighten me or atleast point me in the right way to solve the following inequality

Many thanks!!

Comment: here is an introduction to MathJax http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

$\log(x)$ is defined for $x>0$

and $\log(2-x)$ is for $2-x>0\iff x<2$

So, we need $0<x<2$

Now $x(2-x)<10\iff x^2-2x+10>0$

Now for real $x,x^2-2x+10=(x-1)^2+9\ge9>0$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes! Thanks I understood it now!

Answer (score 0):

For $x\in(0,2)$ we have:

$$\log (x)+\log(2-x)=\log[x(2-x)].$$

Since $x(2-x)$ has roots of $0$ and $2$, its maximum is at $1$. Thus $x(2-x)\leq 1$. Therefore $$\log(x)+\log(2-x)\leq \log(1)= 0<1$$ for all $x\in(0,2)$.